# How can I override the post title when a post is set to sticky?

Tags: title, sticky-post

I want to display my selected post as top post which will appear in the top of my post list. I use sticky post for this, but there is a problem in the sticky post option. It shows selected post at the top, but I want to show the top post with a custom title.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help. Please have a look at the help center and learn [how to ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We need narrowly-scoped and precise questions to provide canonical answers. We always want to know what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck in that process. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you wanna prepend the word "Special: " to every stick post's title you can place the following in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'sticky_title' );
function sticky_title( $title ) {

    // Check if a post is set to sticky.
    if ( is_sticky() ) {

        // Prepend "Special: " to post title.
        return 'Special: ' . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

---

> I want's to design this 'special : ' word into different color and i
>   wants this will appear my every sticky post's left corner... How can i
>   do this?

You could do that with just CSS using [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) or by [hooking into `post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters). Normally the `<article>` tag already comes with a `.sticky` class.

If you use a custom theme you can simply have a look at the Twenty Nineteen theme's `template-parts/content/content.php` and use that approach yourself in your `home.php` or in whatever template you need it:

> ```
> if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) {
>     printf( '<span class="sticky-post">%s</span>', _x( 'Featured', 'post', 'twentynineteen' ) );
> }
> ```

[image]

Comment: I want's to design this 'special : ' word into different color and i wants this will appear my every sticky post's left corner... How can i do this?

Comment: @user166923 – Answer updated.